# I want to download bigquery result from my own python code and something wrong with my authentication

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery

I am trying to download bigQuery results from GCP and I was following the instruction on GCP documentation [GCP authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started?authuser=1). It tells me to create a service account which I did, however, the output tells me that this service account has no permission to access the table

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table dbd-sdlc-prod:HKG_NORMALISED.HKG_NORMALISED: User does not have permission to query table dbd-sdlc-prod:HKG_NORMALISED.HKG_NORMALISED.
```

This reminds me that the table I wished to query was provided by a third party, they grant my account permission to access these data and the permission was only granted for my google account. I wish to find a way to authenticate it with my own account instead of a service account to download the query result, will it be possible and how can I do that exactly?
And following is the role for my test service account, I believe I have set them right as the top role "owner". Thanks in advance

---

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bqclient = bigquery.Client()

# Download query results.
query_string = """
SELECT
    Date_Time,
    Price,
    Volume,
    Market_VWAP,
    Qualifiers AS Qualifiers,
    Ex_Cntrb_ID,
    Qualifiers AS TradeCategory
FROM
    `dbd-sdlc-prod.HKG_NORMALISED.HKG_NORMALISED`
WHERE
    RIC = '1606.HK'
    AND (Date_Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-07-11 00:00:00.000000') AND
    TIMESTAMP('2016-07-11 23:59:59.999999'))
    AND Type="Trade"
    AND Volume >0
    AND Price >0
"""

dataframe = (
    bqclient.query(query_string)
    .result()
    .to_dataframe(
        # Optionally, explicitly request to use the BigQuery Storage API. As of
        # google-cloud-bigquery version 1.26.0 and above, the BigQuery Storage
        # API is used by default.
        create_bqstorage_client=True,
    )
)
print(dataframe.head())
```

Comment: Please edit your question to remove all all [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data)  on it. Where are you running your Python code, cloud console, vm, notebook ? could you please provide the relevant parts of your code where you authenticate and execute your query.

Comment: I have removed all PII now and thank you for reminding me. I am running my python code locally on a windows machine. The code I used is pasted below. I believe authenticating as the end-user will resolve the problem

Comment: I've posted the code on Answers field. Please delete and add on you question editing it.
Are using the google cloud sdk on your terminal, if yes, You  can just run `gcloud auth login`. If not, you will have to [Authenticate as an end user](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user?authuser=1).

Answer (score 0):

If are you using Are using the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) you can just run `gcloud auth login` and authenticate on your google account.

If not, you will have to Authenticate as an end user, [here is](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user?authuser=1) the details and examples of how to do that.

On your code, you will have to add the code for authenticate your application. *(Don't forget to do the other steps in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user?authuser=1))*

Your code will be like this:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google_auth_oauthlib import flow

#--- Authentication

appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    "client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
)

if launch_browser:
    appflow.run_local_server()
else:
    appflow.run_console()

credentials = appflow.credentials
project = 'user-project-id'


#---

bqclient = bigquery.Client(project=project, credentials=credentials)

# Download query results.
query_string = """
SELECT
    Date_Time,
    Price,
    Volume,
    Market_VWAP,
    Qualifiers AS Qualifiers,
    Ex_Cntrb_ID,
    Qualifiers AS TradeCategory
FROM
    `dbd-sdlc-prod.HKG_NORMALISED.HKG_NORMALISED`
WHERE
    RIC = '1606.HK'
    AND (Date_Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-07-11 00:00:00.000000') AND
    TIMESTAMP('2016-07-11 23:59:59.999999'))
    AND Type="Trade"
    AND Volume >0
    AND Price >0
"""

dataframe = (
    bqclient.query(query_string)
    .result()
    .to_dataframe(
        # Optionally, explicitly request to use the BigQuery Storage API. As of
        # google-cloud-bigquery version 1.26.0 and above, the BigQuery Storage
        # API is used by default.
        create_bqstorage_client=True,
    )
)
print(dataframe.head())
```